# Can server permission rights affect page loading speed

Tags: wordpress, performance, file-permissions, server

I changed my WP-file permissions as one tutorial showed (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/08/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/)

Now gtmetrix shows that my site is slower. Can those permissions cause that?

Comment: I dont think so. Permission change have no concern with site loading and Gtmetrix.